# How to fix Foundry Nuke Runtime Error: Read1?

Tags: python, video, runtime-error, render, nuke

After rendering nuke video in python I caught

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
document_celery_worker_1  |   File "/usr/src/morda/vc/nuke/motions/scale_in_scale_out.py", line 79, in apply
document_celery_worker_1  |     nuke.render(output)
document_celery_worker_1  | RuntimeError: Read1: /tmp/tmpq6ri2xk9.mov:
```

this traceback. Interesting that output looks correct anyway. But I want to get rid of this exception. Unfortunately there is no detail explanation of this. Any ideas what's the problem?

This is how I read file:

```
content = nuke.createNode("Read")
content["file"].fromUserText(content_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be something along the lines of "write1 cannot be executed over multiple frames", but without seeing the code & script there's no way to be sure. If you save the script created from code as a .nk, open it and try rendering in the app, does it give you more relevant info?

Comment: I added a code with how I read files.

Comment: that looks fine to me, i would add nuke.saveScriptAs(xxx) at the end, then open that script and see if you can reproduce the error in gui mode.